# Capturing client Datetimeoffset in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

i have a web service that saves some events from users all over the world. The users can later log in to a report system and view their events. I would need to display the event timestamps in their local time.

I can use the `DateTimeOffset` db field in `sql server 2008` behind the `WCF service`. But I'm confused about how to convert this on the web service. When the client calls my web service event method, they need to send the datetime parameter because the time of the actual event may be different from the time service receives it.

if I try to convert it on the server as `DateTimeOffset dtOffset = eventTime;`, it is going to convert it based on the server's time.

How can I do this the right way?

Answer (score 2):

You should store time in UTC format in the database and where ever you want to display the time, just use ToLocalTime() of DateTime object to convert the UTC time to the time zone on the client machine.

Comment: wouldn't it show the local time of the server? the server could be in one location and clients will be all over the world.

Comment: You can calculate the datetime offset in javascript on the client side, send it as a hidden field to the server and then do a diff of the utc time and the datetime offset. Following link can explain it in more details  http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Rendering-ASPNET-UTC-time-as-local-time-of-the-browsers-time-zone.aspx